# Tags matching database query

Tags: mongodb, database

I need an external view on this problem, around a database query I want to make.
Let's say that I have:

- Object 1 with tags: a, b, c
- Object 2 with tags: a, b, f
- Object 3 with tags: a, f

.

- User 1 with tags: a, b, g, f

**I have the tags for User 1, now I want to get Object 2 and Object 3 without fetching all objects.**
User could have 10+ tags.

Anyone with tips/idea to approach this? I can't get around it and I am not sure if that's possible with this data structure.

Comment: Tags is an array in the document? All three should match because they share tags with User 1? Sounds like you want `$in` here as in `{ "tags": { "$in": [ "a", "b", "g", "f" ] } }` searching the collection with Objects. But your question really could be more clear.

Comment: You mean, you're trying to get `User 1`'s tags, then get all `Objects` that have only **matching** tags?

Comment: Yes tags are an array in both the User and the Object.

I would need to fetch the Objects where all tags completely match the User's but the User could have additional tags.

So Object has a,b,c and User has a,b,c,e,r,t,g -> it will match
But Object has a,b,d and User has a,b,c,e,r,t,g -> it doesn't match.

My solution for now is to make some combinations but it can generate a high number of combinations.. (sorry for the formatting of my response)